# AVD for API 14 (Android 4.0) simply doesn't work

Tags: android, sdk, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-virtual-device

Having built an application for Android Minimum SDK of API 14 I wanted to test this on its lowest possible version.

It works fine and the emulator runs fine for API 16.

Emulator runs fine for API 10 but the application crashes, as expected.

I have tried several emulator set ups for API 14 but none of them seems to boot. Emulator starts up but screen stays black, no Android logo.

MY build environment is all Android Studio, including the SDK and emulator images.

I have the SDK and ARM EABI v7a image for APIs 10, 14, 16 and 18 but 14 is the only one giving issues.

All running on a MAC (Lion 10.8.2) and am now at a loss as to why the emulator is not playing ball, any help to get the emulator for API 14 running would be appreciated.

When run the console loops with the message "Device is not ready. Waiting for 20 sec." and emulator screen stays blank, even after a ten minute wait.

Below is a screen grab of one of the failing emulator setups:

[image]

SDK Manager packages installed are:

[image]

Comment: Since there are insignificant numbers of API Level 14 devices, I would not worry about it one iota. https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: Superb, many thanks for this. Can at least tell the client that his Onyx Iris 8 device he wants this on is pointless.

Comment: I'd phrase it more as that either there's an update for that device to 4.0.3 that should be applied, or the client *really* needs to choose another hardware vendor. Nobody should be shipping hardware on 4.0.0-4.0.2.

Comment: Thanks Commons. I did speak to the vendor about upgrading but apparently this particular device is not supported anymore. Their answer was (Verbatum) "You could approach the members on xda-developers.com and enquire about a possible custom ROM for the Iris, which is a Telechips device. There is a small community on XDA.".

In a nutshell I did not quote the client for this and will simply advise they use 4.0.3 as a minimum which so far has tested fine within the emulator.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try unchecking "Use Host GPU" some emulator images just can't handle it.

Comment: Thanks Leandro, that seems to allow the AVD for API 14 to work and boot now. Having said that I'll still stand with CommonsWare's recommendation regarding the fact that API 14 is seldom used and will advise client as such. Accepted your answer though as its direct to my question. Thanks. John.